# PHP / json encode wrongly interprets as associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Edit1: **The problem:** I want to convert in php a associative array to a indexed one. So I can return it via json_encode as an array and not as an object. For this I try to fill the missing keys. Here the description:

Got a small problem, I need to transfer a json_encoded array as an array to js. At the moment it returns an Object. I´m working with Angular so I really need an Array. I try to explain it as much as possible.

```
$arrNew[0][5][0][0][1]["id"] = 1;
//$arrNew[0][0][0][0][1] = "";
//$arrNew[0][1][0][0][1] = "";
//$arrNew[0][2][0][0][1] = "";
//$arrNew[0][3][0][0][1] = "";
//$arrNew[0][4][0][0][1] = "";
$arrNew[0][5][0][0][1]["name"] = 'Test';
var_dump($arrNew);
```

[image]

So if I return it now It returns the second element as object cause of the missing index 0-4 and the 4th element cause of the missing index 0 (associative array -> object)

So if I uncomment the block it works like a charm. Now I have the problem its not every time the element 5 sometime 3, 4 or something else so I build a function which adds them automaticly:

```
$objSorted = cleanArray($arrNew);
function cleanArray($array){
    end($array);
    $max = key($array) + 1; //Get the final key as max!
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        if(!isset($array[$i])) {
            $array[$i] = '';
        } else {
            end($array[$i]);
            $max2 = key($array[$i]) + 1;
            for($i2 = 0; $i2 < $max2; $i2++) {
            .... same code repeats here for every index
```

So if I vardump it it returns:
[image]

**The problem:**
On js side its still an object, what I also see is that the elements are not sorted. So I think somehow PHP sees it still as an associative array. Any clue why this happens ? The key is set with the index of the loop and has to be a integer value.

PS: I know reworking it in JS is possible but would have be done nearly on every request with a huge load of loops

Comment: I'm unclear… do you need the key `5` in there? Then it can't be encoded as an array. Or are you asking how to get rid of the key `5` so it can be encoded as array? What JSON data do you expect exactly?

Comment: @deceze  I need the key 5 and return it via json_encode as an array. So i try to fill the missing keys with zero values

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Might want to [edit] the question to clarify that.

Comment: Do you want to get arrays instead of objects in JS?

Comment: And If someone can explain why this one get downvoted so much it would be nice to, I mean I posted a clear example. The output and what I expect. Not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: @axiac Exactly.

Comment: Try to `sort($arrNew[0])` before `json_encode()` (after you add the dummy keys to it.)

Comment: @axiac for real this one works, afterwards the returned json has an array instead of an object. The problem is now just I have to loop trough all keys and sort them. But anyway this is exactly the solution I needed. You can post it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Doomenik it should be [`ksort($arrNew[0])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). Forgive my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you create a sparse multidimensional array of objects. Because the arrays have gaps in the keys, [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) produces objects on some levels but you need it to produce arrays for all but the most inner level.

The following function fills the missing keys (starting from `0` until the maximum value used as numeric key in an array) on all array levels. It then sorts each array by their keys to make sure `json_encode()` encodes it as array and not object.

The sorting is needed, otherwise `json_encode()` generates an object; this behaviour is explained in a [note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-notes) on the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) documentation page:

> When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric sequence starting from 0, all keys are encoded as strings, and specified explicitly for each key-value pair.

```
// If $arr has numeric keys (not all keys are tested!) then returns
// an array whose keys are a continuous numeric sequence starting from 0.
// Operate recursively for array values of $arr
function fillKeys(array $arr)
{
    // Fill the numeric keys of all values that are arrays
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $arr[$key] = fillKeys($value);
        }
    }

    $max = max(array_keys($arr));
    // Sloppy detection of numeric keys; it may fail you for mixed type keys!
    if (is_int($max)) {
        // Fill the missing keys; use NULL as value
        $arr = $arr + array_fill(0, $max, NULL);
        // Sort by keys to have a continuous sequence
        ksort($arr);
    }

    return $arr;
}

// Some array to test
$arrNew[0][5][0][0][1]["id"] = 1;
$arrNew[0][3][0][2][1]["id"] = 2;
$arrNew[0][5][0][0][1]["name"] = 'Test';


echo("============= Before ==============\n");
echo(json_encode($arrNew)."\n");

$normal = fillKeys($arrNew);

echo("============= After ==============\n");
echo(json_encode($normal)."\n");
```

The output:

```
============= Before ==============
[{"5":[[{"1":{"id":1,"name":"Test"}}]],"3":[{"2":{"1":{"id":2}}}]}]
============= After ==============
[[null,null,null,[[null,null,[null,{"id":2}]]],null,[[[null,{"id":1,"name":"Test"}]]]]]
```

The line `$arr = $arr + array_fill(0, $max, NULL);` uses `NULL` as values for the missing keys. This is, I think, the best for the Javascript code that parses the array (you can use `if (! arr[0])` to detect the dummy values).

You can use the empty string (`''`) instead of `NULL` to get a shorter JSON:

```
[["","","",[["","",["",{"id":2}]]],"",[[["",{"id":1,"name":"Test"}]]]]]
```

but it requires slightly longer code on the JS side to detect the dummy values (`if (arr[0] != '')`).

Comment: First ty for all the work, actually if you read my question I already had a function which fills the gaps. Problem is it still interprets it as  associative array and this way as an object in js. The keys are also now rightly sorted even before ksort. The funny thing is if I add the ksort which does not change anything, it really turns it from an associative array to an nummeric one, which than works in JS. I have no clue why, but really ty. I would never have tried sorting an array which is already sorted  :D Ah and the hint with NULL I will use for sure too.

Comment: I saw you already have a function that fills the gaps, I just didn't like it ;-) Mine works on any number of levels. Before `ksort()`, the keys are: 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (you can see them in the `var_dump()` you posted in the question). They are not [*"a continuous numeric sequence starting from 0"*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-notes) and `json_encode()` produces an object to keep their order on decode. After `ksort()` they are: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and they can safely be ignored on encoding. Encoding it as array produces the same result on decoding.

Comment: I rebuilded it to add the after filling the holes so it had 0,1,2,3,4,5, still didn´t want to work but ksort() fixed it. Anyway will rebuild it to your filling algorithm. Like it also more than mine :)